# Сложный sql-запрос некорректно извлекает данные

Tags: mysql

Нужно извлечь из бд все чаты на которые подписан пользователь, имеются след. таблицы:

Подписки: chats_subscriptions

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cid   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Чаты: chats

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| owner  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| label  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| type   | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | private           |                |
| status | int(1)       | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
| date   | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Сообщения: messages

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| cid       | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| sender    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| recipient | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date      | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| content   | text      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| del       | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| status    | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Следующим запросом я пытаюсь достать все чаты на которые подписан пользователь, с кол-вом не прочитанных сообщений:

```
SELECT `cs`.`cid`, `ch`.`owner` AS `cOwner`, `ch`.`label` AS `cLabel`, 
`ch`.`type` AS `cType`, `ch`.`status` AS `cStatus`, `ch`.`date` AS `cDate`, 
COUNT(`msg`.`id`) AS `countMsg`  FROM `chats_subscriptions` `cs`  
LEFT JOIN `chats` `ch` ON `ch`.`id`=`cs`.`cid`  
LEFT JOIN `messages` `msg` ON `msg`.`cid`=`ch`.`id` AND `msg`.`del` IS NULL AND `msg`.`status` IS NULL AND `msg`.`recipient`=`cs`.`uid`   
WHERE `cs`.`uid` = 2
```

Такой запрос работает не совсем правильно, он извлекает информацию верно, но если юзер подписан на три чата, то все-равно вернется только одна строка. Вот если убрать LEFT JOIN `messages` - тогда все работает верно, но нужно же извлекать кол-во сообщений (ещё и хочется добавить текст последнего непрочитанного сообщения). Подскажите, в чем косяк?

И кстати, если по вашему мнению это кривая структура бд, с удовольствием выслушаю ваши более оптимальные предложения! (задача была такой: сделать переписку в лс на сайте с возможность добавлять/удалять собеседников, поэтому я и решил представить все в виде чатов с подписками на них)

**! UPDATE 3:**

Попытался сделать такой запрос, все вроде правильно, но извлекает только одну строку, хотя подписок (чатов у пользователя) больше:

```
SELECT cs.cid, u.login AS cLogin, u.ava AS cAva, ch.owner AS cOwner, lm.content AS lmContent, lm.lmDate AS lmDate,
 ch.label AS cLabel, ch.type AS cType, ch.status AS cStatus, ch.date AS cDate,COUNT(*) AS countMsg
   FROM chats_subscriptions cs  
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=cs.uid  
    INNER JOIN chats ch ON ch.id=cs.cid  
    LEFT JOIN messages msg ON msg.cid=ch.id AND msg.del IS NULL AND msg.status IS NULL AND msg.recipient=cs.uid 

    JOIN (
                SELECT lm.id, lm.content, lm.cid, lm.date AS lmDate
                FROM messages lm
                WHERE lm.status IS NULL AND lm.date = (

                    SELECT MAX(date)
                       FROM messages
                       GROUP BY lm.id
                       HAVING lm.id                                        
                    ) GROUP BY lm.cid 

    ) lm ON lm.cid = cs.cid

    WHERE cs.uid = 2 GROUP BY cs.cid
```

Может где-то не хватает чего-то или что-то лишнее? Не могу разобраться...

Comment: @Mike, да, вы правы, надо было сгруппировать, спасибо! Я еще дополнил вопрос, можете дать развернутый ответ по структуре? и как извлечь последнее сообщение (msg.content)?

Comment: @Mike я добавил LEFT JOIN messages last_msg ON last_msg.cid=cs.cid AND last_msg.status IS NULL и в select - MAX(fx_last_msg.date) но всеравно выводится первое сообщение а не последнее. Через left join это должно работать? Или там нужно делать join(и как-то тут select....)?

Comment: @Mike обновил вопрос с запросом кот я делаю и что у меня не получается. Если можете отпишитесь в ответе, я заапрувлю его)

Comment: @Mike все равно не правильно работает: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5e08b01744127347318d32afff4ab5e6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подводя итоги переписки:

1. При использовании в запросе хотя бы одной групповой функции (например count()) по умолчанию происходит группировка всех данных до единственной записи. Поэтому надо обязательно задавать предложение `group by` для получения данных в правильном разрезе.
2. По структуре БД: Поле "recipient" в messages если и использовать, то только для приватных сообщений, вне комнат чата. В таблицу подписок (chats_subscriptions) предлагаю добавить поле "дата последнего просмотра" (`seen_date`) в котором фиксировать кто из подписчиков *когда* последний раз читал комнату. Поле status скорее всего так же после этого становится ненужным
3. Поле `msg.del` из таблицы messages выносим в таблицу "удаленные сообщения" со структурой `create table msg_delited( msg_id int not null, uid int not null, primary key (msg_id,uid) )`
4. Запрос получающий, кроме всего прочего, последнее сообщение из чата выглядит как то так

   ```
    SELECT `cs`.`cid`, `ch`.`owner` AS `cOwner`, `ch`.`label` AS `cLabel`, 
          `ch`.`type` AS `cType`, `ch`.`status` AS `cStatus`, `ch`.`date` AS `cDate`, 
           COUNT(`msg`.`id`) AS `countMsg`, -- Общее кол-во сообщений
           sum( if(cs.seen_date < msg.date, 1, 0) ) as countNew, -- Кол-во непрочитанных сообщений
           substr(max(concat(msg.date,msg.content)),20) as content, -- Текст последнего сообщения
           (
            exists(
              select 1 from chats_subscriptions sub
               where sub.cid=cs.cid and sub.seen_date>=max(msg.date)
               limit 1
            )
           ) as chSeen -- Кто то уже видел последнее сообщение
     FROM `chats_subscriptions` `cs`
     JOIN `chats` `ch` ON `ch`.`id`=`cs`.`cid`  
     LEFT JOIN `messages` `msg`
            ON `msg`.`cid`=`ch`.`id`
     LEFT JOIN msg_delited md
            ON md.msg_id=msg.id
           and md.uid=cs.uid    -- <<--- Признаки "удаленных" только для текущего пользователя
   --      AND `msg`.`del` IS NULL AND `msg`.`status` IS NULL <<--- скорее всего не нужно
   --      AND `msg`.`recipient`=`cs`.`uid`   <<--- Это уже не нужно
   WHERE `cs`.`uid` = 2
     AND md.msg_id is NULL -- <<--- Получаем только НЕ удаленные сообщения
   group by cs.cid
   ```

Насторожила проверка некого "получателя сообщения". В виду описанной задачи с чат-комнатой с несколькими говорящими, не понятно, кто является получателем сообщения. По идее там может быть отправитель, но получают сообщения (если мы в режиме чата, а не личного сообщения) все, кто подписан на разговор. Значит поле `recipient` было бы логично оставлять NULL. И при подсчете сообщений в комнате видимо надо учитывать все сообщения. Или например с recepient is null, что бы отделить совсем личные.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42823/discussion-on-answer-by-mike--sql----).